# Как выкачать байты из базового потока System.IO.stream используя powershell

Tags: powershell

Есть такая функция

```
[System.Net.HttpWebRequest] $webRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('URl')
$webRequest.Timeout = 3000
$webRequest.Method = 'POST'
$webRequest.ContentType = 'multipart/form-data'
$webRequest.ContentLength = $data.Length;
$requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream()
$requestStream.Write($data, 0, $data.Length)
$requestStream.Flush()
$requestStream.Close()
[System.Net.HttpWebResponse] $webResponse = $webRequest.GetResponse()
```

аналог

```
$webclient = new-object system.net.WebClient;
$streamReader =  $webclient.UploadData($url ,"POST",$data);
```

как с помощью первой функции выкачать байты из базового потока System.IO.stream при условии что свойство длиный базового потока не показывает количество принимаемых байтов от сервера(сервер не отдает длину передаваемых байтов) из-за этого не получается воспользоваться стандартными методами

```
$streamReader = New-Object IO.BinaryReader($webResponse.GetResponseStream())
$streamReader.ReadBytes($streamReader.BaseStream.Length)
```

т.е. мы не знаем длину базового потока $streamReader.BaseStream.Length.
был придуман костыль как выкачать байты

```
Try{
    While(1){
        [byte[]]$bytes+=[byte[]]$streamResponse.ReadByte()
    }
    }Catch{}
```

т.е. когда мы выкачиваем все байты из потока в конце ловим -1 что указывает на конец потока и этот -1 генерирует ошибку тем самым мы выходить из цикла.

Метод рабочий но не совсем правильный при передачи большого потока данных, данный цикл перегружает процессор и зависает скрипт. Можеть быть есть какие то более правильные решения, при условии что мы не знает длину передаваемого потока?

Comment: `$ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream; $rs = $webResponse.GetResponseStream(); $rs.CopyTo($ms)`

Comment: и? приходит все к тому же что у нас нет свойства $ms.Length и натыкаемся опять на наш костыль для выкачки байтов из памяти
Try{While(1){[byte[]]$bytes+=[byte[]]$ms.ReadByte()}}Catch{}

Comment: *приходит все к тому же что у нас нет свойства `$ms.Length`* С чего это вдруг его нет? К тому же, зачем Вы вообще читаете из `MemoryStream`? Чем Вам метод `ToArray()` не угодил?

Comment: как я понимаю логику работы но могу ошибаться: 
1) $webResponse.GetResponseStream() - отдает обьект HttpWebResponse где в обьекте есть свойство ContentLength в моем случаи оно равно  -1 т.к. сервер не отдает свойство.
2) $rs = $webResponse.GetResponseStream();  получаем базовый stream который берет свойство Length из $webResponse.ContentLength
3) $ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStreams = New-Object IO.MemoryStream; $rs.CopyTo($ms) соотвественно в потоке $rs нет свойства Length cooтвественно и в $ms.Length и в память потока $ms не чего не копируется. Данный вывод основан практическим путем.

Comment: `CopyTo` никак не использует свойств `Length` исходного потока.

Comment: проблема наверно в том что обьект $rs не обладает методом CopyTo

Comment: CopyTo
Method invocation failed because [System.Net.ConnectStream] doesn't contain a method named 'CopyTo'.

Comment: PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: да PowerShell 2.0. 
а как вам вот такой способ, но опять же не понятно в какой кодировке сервер возращает байты
$streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($webResponse.GetResponseStream());
$rs = $streamReader.ReadToEnd();
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.getbytes($rs)

Comment: в powershell 5.0 все отработало отлично,спс. Cейчас возник просто спортивный интерес, как это победить в PowerShell 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одним из самых простых вариантов будет скопировать поток в `MemoryStream`:

```
$rs = $webResponse.GetResponseStream()
$ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream
$rs.CopyTo($ms)
```

Если используется PowerShell 2.0 и метод `CopyTo` недоступен, то можно реализовать его самому:

```
function CopyTo-Stream {
    param(
        [IO.Stream] $Source,
        [IO.Stream] $Destination
    )
    $Buffer = New-Object Byte[] 64kb
    while($Read = $Source.Read($Buffer, 0, $Buffer.Length)) {
        $Destination.Write($Buffer, 0, $Read);
    }
}

$rs = $webResponse.GetResponseStream()
$ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream
CopyTo-Stream $rs $ms
```

Comment: т.е. он будет читать кусками по 64kb не зависимо от кол-во байт находящихся в $rs и скидывать их в кучу?

Comment: Если не вдаваться в детали, то да.

Comment: Квест пройдет, спасибо большое за помощь!!!!!!

Comment: А можете в двух словах обьяснить почему так происходит если с функцией делаю CopyTo-Stream $rs $ms то все копируется если делаю без, а напряму $rs = $webResponse.GetResponseStream()
$ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream   $Buffer = New-Object Byte[] 64kb
    while($Read = $rs.Read($Buffer, 0, $Buffer.Length)) {
        $ms.Write($Buffer, 0, $Read);
не копирует, по факту получается одно и тоже что в функцию передать обьект что с ними взаимодействовать на прямую

Comment: Я не вижу явной причины, почему это может не работать.